# Не отображается приложение вк через https

Tags: https

Есть приложение вконтакте работающее через ифрейм. По протоколу http оно открывается нормально, но когда я захожу в вк через https самого приложения не вижу и в хроме в правом углу появляется серебристый значек щита с надписью - страница содержит скрипт из не проверенных источников.

Что делать в таком случае ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

предпологаю, что в скрипте есть обращение к сервер по http. Нужно чтобы было https для всех подключений на странице.

Comment: да, есть такое. т.е. нужно чтобы на нашем сайте тоже было https ? иных вариантов нет ?

Comment: да, именно так и другого не дано. хотел бы обратить внимание на то, что сертификат должне быть настоящий.